# Issue in adding decimal values stored as varchar

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a staging table with two amount columns, created as varchar2 types to allow import from excel. Later these fields are validated to make sure they contains numeric data & summation of values for each row should greater than zero, before making the updates to actual table.

I have a function to validate whether the column contains any non numeric data, which works as expected.

```
   FUNCTION f_isnumber (pin_string IN VARCHAR2)
      RETURN INT
   IS
      v_new_num   NUMBER;
   BEGIN
      IF TRIM (pin_string) IS NOT NULL
      THEN
         v_new_num := TO_NUMBER (pin_string);


         RETURN 1;
      END IF;

      RETURN 0;
   EXCEPTION
      WHEN VALUE_ERROR
      THEN
         RETURN 0;
   END f_isnumber;
```

Next is I wanted to list all the rows where value of two amount field is zero. Below query works where I am just selecting the total of both columns.

```
WITH CTE1
     AS (SELECT TO_NUMBER (PURCH_AMT) + TO_NUMBER (SELL_AMT) AS Total, ROW_ID
           FROM STG_MAINTENANCE
          WHERE     PKG_MAINTENANCE.f_isnumber (PURCH_AMT) > 0
                AND PKG_MAINTENANCE.f_isnumber (SELL_AMT) > 0)
SELECT TO_NUMBER (Total), CTE1.*
  FROM CTE1
```

But as soon as I add where clause, the query fails with error "ORA-01722: invalid number"

```
WITH CTE1
     AS (SELECT TO_NUMBER (PURCH_AMT) + TO_NUMBER (SELL_AMT) AS Total, ROW_ID
           FROM STG_MAINTENANCE
          WHERE     PKG_MAINTENANCE.f_isnumber (PURCH_AMT) > 0
                AND PKG_MAINTENANCE.f_isnumber (SELL_AMT) > 0)
SELECT TO_NUMBER (Total), CTE1.*
  FROM CTE1
 WHERE Total = 0
```

Table contains both valid numbers, spaces & valid decimals, zero etc. I was hoping inner where clause will eliminate all non numeric values & I would only get valid decimal values & if user has imported 0 or 0.00
But somehow invalid number error comes up.

Sample Data:

```
Create table STG_MAINTENANCE (ROW_ID INT, PURCH_AMT VARCHAR2(500), SELL_AMT VARCHAR2(500));

INSERT INTO STG_MAINTENANCE values(1, 'A','4.5');
INSERT INTO STG_MAINTENANCE values(2, '0','0.0');
INSERT INTO STG_MAINTENANCE values(3, '5.5','4.5');
INSERT INTO STG_MAINTENANCE values(4, '','4.5');
INSERT INTO STG_MAINTENANCE values(5, 'B','C');
INSERT INTO STG_MAINTENANCE values(6, '','');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think The way Oracle is processing your query causes the error in your query.

For your example, You can use `MATERIALIZE` hint and write your query like the following:

```
WITH CTE1 AS (
    SELECT /*+MATERIALIZE*/
        TO_NUMBER(PURCH_AMT) + TO_NUMBER(SELL_AMT) AS TOTAL,
        ROW_ID
    FROM
        STG_MAINTENANCE
    WHERE
        PKG_MAINTENANCE.F_ISNUMBER(PURCH_AMT) > 0
        AND PKG_MAINTENANCE.F_ISNUMBER(SELL_AMT) > 0
)
SELECT
    TO_NUMBER(TOTAL),
    CTE1.*
FROM
    CTE1
WHERE
    TOTAL = 0
```

You can learn more about `MATERIALIZE` hint from oracle docs.

Hope this is helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Yes, I will have to learn more about the hints.